# Unable to redirect to url using Server Side Swift Perfect

Tags: swift, redirect, perfect, server-side-swift

I'm using Server Side Swift Perfect framework for web services.
Mustache module for serving static/dynamic content.

I want to implement login functionality following a redirect to the homepage on Successful authentication. 
"I searched everywhere but didn't find any such feature which redirects to a url"

Here is the code I'm using for implementing login-

```
func signin(request:HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse) {
    do {
        var errorMessage:String;
        var values = MustacheEvaluationContext.MapType()
        let email:String = request.param(name: "email")!
        let password:String = request.param(name: "password")!
        print("Email -> \(email) & Password -> \(password)")
        //After Authentication
        //Yay I want to go back to home page.
        mustacheRequest(request: request, response: response, handler: MustacheHelper(values: values), templatePath: webroot + "/index.html")
        // Sadly this doesn't work, it just renders the homepage without changing the url or 'without redirecting'
        response.completed()
} catch {
        print(error)
        logError(error.localizedDescription)
        response.setBody(string: "An error occured \(error)").completed()
    }
}
```

I think the company PerfectlySoft fogot to put this feature. May be I should report it.
Anybody knows what could be the solution to my problem? Please tell.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I myself figured out the solution. This feature of url redirection is not included in PerfectHTTP or PerfectHTTPServer module itself. You have to import another module -> [Perfect-OAuth2](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-OAuth2.git) by PerfectlySoft. 'redirect' method is directly declared under HTTPResponse extension. OR you can do it by adding your own like this,

```
extension HTTPResponse {
    public func redirect(path: String) {
        self.status = .found
        self.setHeader(.location, value: path)
        self.completed()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save my day  

Comment: Perfect framework got me a jumpstart for Server-side swift but I don't use this framework anymore as its competitor (Vapor) is constantly giving updates and works on latest low-level swift APIs. I don't know about future of this Perfect framework. 

I'll suggest you to use Vapor 4 framework https://vapor.codes. It's been officially released now.